# Using Google CDN with the sprockets assets compiler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sprockets

This seems quite trivial but couldnt find it in the forums or rails asset pipeline guides.

### In short

How can I inform sprockets to skip the asset pipeline for the jquery ui css of the  'jquery-rails' gem.

### In long:

I am trying to use 'jquery-rails' gems with the Google jquery CDN's.

Hence in the I am just including the jquery_ujs and adding the jquery related scripts in the application layout:

application.js.erb:

```
//= require bootstrap-twipsy.js
//= require jquery-glowing
//= require jquery_ujs
```

application.html.erb:

```
= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jqueryui.min.js"
```

For the css', I am not including the jquery-ui css in the application.css and adding it in the layouts file too.

application.css.scss.erb:

```
 *= require_directory .
 *= require active_scaffold
 *= require_self
```

In production environment, the compiled css file includes the jquery-css code too, since its in the assets pipeline of the 'jquery-rails' gem.

So how can I inform sprockets to skip the asset pipeline for the jquery ui css of the  'jquery-rails' gem.

---

If this is not possible in rails, what is the best way to handle this sittuation.

I thought about removing the jquery-rails gem, and adding the jquery_ujs javascript manually to the system, but then I have to deal with the installation of new releases rather than executing a simple 'bundle update'

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the active_scaffold gem, [right here](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_scaffold.css.erb#L1100) if you want the code reference. It includes the jquery-ui CSS.

To remove this you'll need to replicate the entire active scaffold css code in your app/assets/stylsheets folder (as `my_active_scaffold`), removing the link to jquery-ui. I am assuming that the ActiveScaffold erb at the end of the file will still run in this context.

Then just include it:

```
 *= require my_active_scaffold
```

Comment: I believe that you are right about active scaffold. I actually used a hack to overwrite active scaffold assets by adding blank versions to public folder. But it seems it does not work with the sprockets assets compiler.